# Getting Selected options from Multi Select tag via Javascript and Send via XHR

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm looking to submit a form via an XHR but I'm having trouble getting a hold of the selected data to pass along.

```
<form>
    <select multiple id="select" >
        <option class="userOptions" value="1">Tyler Durden</option>
        <option class="userOptions" value="2">Robert Paulson</option>
        <option class="userOptions" value="3">Marla Singer</option>         
    </select>
</form>
```

What would be the best way to grab hold of the user selected values and pass them off to a page via an XHR?

I've tried things like `document.getElementsByClassName("userOptions").selected` but it's not returning anything. Also, should I pack this up as an array? Or is there a better way to send it? Thanks for your time!

Comment: Why don’t you just use jQuery’s `serialize` method (after giving the select element an appropriate name) …?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function in vanilla Javascript that will help you:

```
function getMultiValue(selectId)
{
    var list     = document.getElementById(selectId),
        selected = [],
        i;
    for (i = 0; i < list.options.length; i++) {
        if (list.options[i].selected) {
            selected.push(list.options[i].value);
        }
    }
    return selected;
}
```

In the case of your example, you must use this way:

```
var values = getMultiValue('select');
```

If you want those values converted to a query string:

```
var queryString = 'select=' + values.implode('&select=');
```

If the values contain special characters, you must do this *before*  the construction of the query string:

```
var i;
for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    values[i] = escape(values[i]);
}
```

Or just change a little the previous function:

```
function getMultiValue(selectId, mustEscape)
{
    var list     = document.getElementById(selectId),
        selected = [],
        i;
    for (i = 0; i < list.options.length; i++) {
        if (list.options[i].selected) {
            selected.push(mustEscape ? escape(list.options[i].value) : list.options[i].value);
        }
    }
    return selected;
}
```

And use it this way:

```
var values      = getMultiValue('select', true),
    queryString = 'select=' + values.implode('&select=');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery and its just simple!

You can do it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Hm2KL/

```
$("#sendbtn").click(function() {

    var data = $("#selectme").val();
    alert(data);

    $.ajax({
        url: ..,
        data: {data}
           etc..
    });

});
```

jQuery Ajax Doc: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/